# firebase init displaying incorrect default projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I wish to use firebase functions. When I input `firebase init`  in my current folder, it displays the incorrect default projects below. These projects displayed are from my google account 1. Currently I am logged into google account 2.

[image]

How would I get `firebase init` to display the correct default projects (the projects from google account 2)? These are the projects from my google account 2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first have to logout from the CLI with the `logout` command and then login again (command `login`) with your google account 2.

See the list of commands here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @JDuh Did the solution described in the anwser worked?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and this was due to an environment variable that was stored on the system, you have to delete it, restart your machine and try the command again